# Using a custom directive with $index of v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom directive inside of a v-for. I need to pass the value of $index into the custom directive, so as to be able to save the datepicker value in an array (I have one date per product). $index always has a value of undefined inside the array though.

```
   <tr v-for="result in results">
      <td>
           <input v-model="shoppingCart[$index].productStartDate" type="text" v-datepicker='shoppingCart[$index].productStartDate'>
      </td>
```

The problem is that the string $index is what is coming through into the custom directive.

The customer directive:

```
 Vue.directive('datepicker', {

        bind: function () {
            var vm = this.vm;
            var key = this.expression;
            $(this.el).datepicker({
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    vm.$set(key, date);
                }
            });
        },
        update: function (val) {
            $(this.el).datepicker('setDate', val);
        }

    });
```

I have tried using this.arg to pass a refence to $index and can't find a way to pass a closure to get the value, but neither worked, I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: just a question, why are you using quotes and arrows for your directive? I though directives were used like properties, first time I saw that notation

Comment: @YerkoPalma - thanks for pointing that out, that was a mistake in my translation of my Laravel blade syntax to html. It's fixed now

Comment: Facing same problem.... help anyone?

Answer (score 2):

For Vue.js 2.x they recommend using the dataset to pass values
so you could add :data-index="index" inside the HTML element and grab it in the directive like this:

```js
Vue.directive('yourDirective', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log('index of element', el.dataset.index); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div 
  v-yourDirective
  v-for="(test,index) in tests" 
  :data-index="index"
>
  
</div>
```